# twoTwo riddle by CodingBat

Tags: python

```
def twoTwo(list_2):

    two_count = list_2.index(2)

    if two_count == 0:
        if list_2[1] == 2:
            print True
        else:
            print False
    elif two_count > 0:
        if list_2[two_count - 1] == 2 or list_2[two_count + 1] == 2:
            print True
        else:
            print False
```

Problem:
Write a function twoTwo(), given an list of ints, return true if every 2 that appears in the list is next to another 2.

```
twoTwo([4, 2, 2, 3]) → true       
twoTwo([2, 2, 4]) → true          
twoTwo([2, 2, 4, 2]) → false
```

It works for the second one, but not the last one, and have not attempted to try the first one...

Comment: The problem statement says to return true if _every_ 2 that appears in the list is next to another 2. `list_2.index(2)` will return the index of the _first_ 2 that appears in the list. You need to rewrite your function to use a loop

Comment: Return does not mean print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y'all are overcomplicating things. This is python; just turn the language of the question into code. Return True if every 2 that appears in the list is next to another 2, return False otherwise.

Equivalently: return False if any 2 that appears in the list is not next to another 2, return True otherwise.

```
def two_two(lst):
    for i, val in enumerate(lst):
        # if any two that appears in the list
        if val == 2:
            left = i > 0 and lst[i - 1] == 2
            right = i < len(lst) - 1 and lst[i + 1] == 2
            # is not next to another two
            if not left and not right:
                return False
    # otherwise,
    return True

print two_two([4, 2, 2, 3]) # True
print two_two([2, 2, 4]) # True
print two_two([2, 4, 2, 4]) # False
print two_two([2, 2, 4, 2]) # False
print two_two([3, 4, 1]) # True
```

Answer (score 1):

One concise solution is to find runs of the same number using `itertools.groupby`, and then check that no run has a key `2` and length 1 (which is checked using `sum(g) == 2` since a run of 2's has sum equal to double its length).

```
import itertools

def two_two(xs):
    return not any(k == sum(g) == 2 for k, g in itertools.groupby(xs))
```

Here's some simple test code:

```
cases = [
    ([], True),
    ([2], False),
    ([2, 2], True),
    ([2, 3], False),
    ([3, 2], False),
    ([4, 2, 2, 3], True),
    ([2, 2, 4], True),
    ([2, 2, 4, 2], False),
    ([2, 2, 2, 3], True),
]

for xs, want in cases:
    got = two_two(xs)
    if got != want:
        print 'two_two(%s) = %d, want %d' % (xs, got, want)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `for` loop to check for the `2`s. A simple example would be like this (not writing the entire function, but you should get the idea ...):

```
for vm1, v, vp1 in zip( list_2, list_2[1:], list_2[2:]):
    if v == 2 and ( vm1 != 2  and vp1 != 2) return False

return True
```

This is much simpler than finding an index.

Remember to check for the first and last 2's separately